# cvGetSize gives bad argument error

Tags: iphone, ios, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to reduce the glare and light reflections from an image to then continue with some more image processing. I found a snippet of code online that supposedly works to select pixels in a range but when I insert into my algorithm, it gives me an error. I've verified that my image data is not `NULL`, so that is not causing the problem. Why am I getting an assertion failure?

**Error:**

> OpenCV Error: Bad argument (Array should be CvMat or IplImage) in cvGetSize, file /Users/user/slave/builds/ios_framework/src/opencv/modules/core/src/array.cpp, line 1238
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception.

**Code:**

```
cv::Mat eye1 = [self cvMatFromUIImage:eye];
cv::Mat eye2;

IplImage imgHSV = *cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(&eye1), 8, 3);    //Assertion fails here
IplImage imgThreshold = *cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(&imgHSV), 8, 1);
cvInRangeS(&imgHSV, cvScalar(0, 0, 90, 0), cvScalar(0, 0, 100, 0) , &imgThreshold);
cv::Mat eye3(&imgThreshold);
```

The original code didn't include the `*` and `&` symbols but Xcode suggested that I place them but the function still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The error you get is because `eye1` is neither `CvMat*` nor `IplImage*`, which `cvGetSize()` expects, but a `cv::Mat`. You need to understand that these three are different types. `cv::Mat` is part of the C++ API, while `CvMat` and `IplImage` belong to the C API, and are deprecated. It is a good idea not to mix the two.

It looks like you want to use the [`cv::inRange()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?#inrange) function, perhaps like this:

```
cv::inRange(eye1, cv::Scalar(0,0,90,0), cv::Scalar(0,0,100,0), eye2);
```

You could then dispense with the `IplImage` variables and the associated manual memory management.

Comment: I would also suggest reading OpenCV's [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/index.html) thoroughly to gain some familiarity with it. Especially because trying to use `cv::inRange()` as written will turn the image black, not what you expect.

Comment: im trying to remove the glare from my images, i know i have to adjust the Scalar values to make it work and i get the concept of different types depending on the language, the problem is im using iOS which is Objective-C, there is no specifics on what to use then, not enough tutorials or examples with opencv and ios

Comment: I'm having some trouble understanding exactly what you want. You can also write Objective-C++, which allows full use of OpenCV's C++ API.

Comment: Im trying to remove the glare from an image so i can then continue doing some filtering and other operations on the image, but i need to remove the glare since it messes up the overall algorithm and accuracy of what im trying to do.

Comment: I understand your overall goal. It sounded like you had an issue trying to use Objective-C. Is this the case? If not, what is your *specific* issue?

Comment: Well my specific issue is that im new to opencv and image processing, i have no problems using iOS and Objective-C. Im trying to reduce glare in an image containing a human eye, from there im changing it to a black and white to measure the iris and then i need to increase the contrast to deferentiate b/w the pupil and iris and then measure the pupil itself. I know its tricky thats why im asking for help here since im also new at image processing